# Evento "onClick()" executando sozinho

Tags: javascript, react, typescript

Essa função está dentro de um `map` e dentro do mesmo, executo `{Idchecker}`

O **item.id** é um valor que vem no Array, eu preciso deste **id** para deletar a publicação que o usuário criou, então pego **idValue** que armazena os identificadores dos posts e comparo com os mesmos existentes, assim, permito que o usuário tenha o botão na sua publicação para deletá-la!

O problema é que o botão está **executando** sem a ação *"clique"* do usuário, contudo ao carregar a página é executado de imediato 2 *requests* de delete.

```ts
const [idValue, setIdValue] = useState([702, 704]);
const [verify, setVerify] = useState(true);

function Idchecker() {
    for (let i = 0; i < idValue.length; i++) {
        if (idValue[i] == item.id) {
            if (idValue[0] != null && verify == true) {
                return (
                    <button onClick={Delete(idValue[0])}>DELETE</button>,
                    setVerify(false)
                )
            } else if (idValue[0 + 1] != null) {
                return (
                    <button onClick={Delete(idValue[0 + 1])}>DELETE</button>
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

// função delete

function Delete(event) {
    axios.delete('http://test/delete' + event + '/', {
        id: event
    }).then(res => { console.log(res) });
}
```

Comment: Não sei como está organizado esse código mas algo como `onClick={this.Delete.bind(this, idvalue[0])}` e mais adiante `onClick={this.Delete.bind(this, idvalue[0 + 1])}` não solucionaria o problema?

Comment: tentei, o click para de ser executado ao carregar a pagina mas o botão não aparece

Comment: @GabrielOliveiraMenezes como você está utilizando componentes funcionais e não classes, para passar parametros na função você precisar fazer dessa forma: `onClick={() => { Delete(idvalue[0 + 1]) }`, caso contrário a função será chamada assim que o componente for renderizado.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou

Answer (score 1):

@GabrielOliveiraMenezes,

Você deverá chamar sua função como callback no evento OnClick.
Ajustando sua tag  para esse modelo:

No primeiro if:

```
<button onClick={() => Delete(idValue[0])}>DELETE</button>
```

No segundo if:

```
<button onClick={() => Delete(idValue[0 + 1])}>DELETE</button>
```

Acredito que isso corrigirá seu problema.

Boa sorte.